# Devexpress ASPxPopupControl not popping up

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, devexpress

For some reason, this code isn't working:

Code-Behind

```
protected void btnNote_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl notePopup = (DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl)Master.FindControl("TaskBar").FindControl("pcNote").FindControl("notePopup");
    notePopup.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
}
```

.aspx (event)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNote" runat="server" Text="Add Note" OnClick="btnNote_Clicked" />
```

I need to write a function that takes this popup control ('notePopup') and displays it, and I believe this is supposed to work, but for some reason, once the page is reloaded, there is no popup.

Comment: I am afraid, it is rather difficult to answer this question.  Please post the aspx markup and also let us know at which moment of the Page Life cycle this code is executed...  Also, is it executed during a callback or postback?

Comment: I posted some more of the code, but since I'm still really new to .net, I guess I'm not sure if a buttonClick triggers a callback or a postback...

Comment: is this button inside the MS UpdatePanel?

Comment: the button IS inside the UpdatePanel, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, although what I'm doing now I'm 100% sure I already did, and I'm not sure what else could have changed that affected my results since then, so I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

@Jordan, try to add the ASPxPopupControl inside the same MS UpdatePanel.  In this case, I believe everything will work properly.  What are your results?

Comment: this is actually what we had, and it does display the popup window. But for some reason, the form submission within the window doesn't work if its opened from the button like that.

Comment: @Jordan, I need more details. Could you please describe the whole scenario?  what you are doing and what you want to achieve...

Comment: With this particular popupcontrol, I want users to be able to just make a note that will be saved to our database. There are two fields in the popup (both required) for a subject and a description, as well as two buttons, on to save the note, and one to cancel. The cancel button works fine, but the save button doesn't do anything in the popup if its opened from the button mentioned above. However, in the taskbar that I have on every page (in site.master), there is another button that activates the same popup, except that it works perfectly.

Comment: The reason I have the initial question is because I was told to have the button display the usercontrol that is attached to the taskbar (that is on every page anyway) rather than initializing a new instance of the usercontrol.

Comment: Does the ASPxPopupControl uses the ContentUrl to specify the inner content?  Or it contains just an aspx mark up with editors and buttons?